# Adding to a stage in EaselJS. One works, one doesn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

The easiest way I can think of adding items to the stage is just to keep a list of items, and then add them all at once. But ...
This code works:

```
    stage.addChild(img1);
    stage.addChild(img2);
    stage.addChild(img3);
    stage.update();
```

This code does not. Why?

```
    var stageList = [img1, img2, img3];
    for (item in stageList){
        stage.addChild(item);
    }
    stage.update();
```

I gotta be doing something stupid, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item will be index or property and not the value in the array. Access the value this way `stageList[item]` and the loop should look like this

```
for (item in stageList){
  stage.addChild(stageList[item]);
}
```

Read more about [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: well, Duh. I (should) know that :)

Comment: I know, sometimes the simplest ones get overlooked :)

Comment: If you use a typed language like TypeScript or Haxe, you would have got an error about this. It might be worth to look in one or the other.

Comment: I have been noodling TypeScript for awhile, so thanks for the tip.